# How to select a CSS element and input value in CSS element with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I completely new with automation testing.

I need to test this web-site: 
https://www.seb.ee/eng/loan-and-leasing/leasing/car-leasing#calculator
When I trying to input value in the calculator field "Price of the vehicle", Robot Framework FAILS with an error: `Element with locator 'id=calc08-sum' not found.`

I tried to use several types of selectors, this is my Test Case:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary 

*** Test Cases ***
Calculator
    Open Browser    http://www.seb.ee/eng/loan-and-leasing/leasing/car-leasing#calculator   chrome 
    Set Browser Implicit Wait    3   
    Maximize Browser Window
    Input Text    id=calc08-sum    1000
```

Also another type of selector was:
`xpath: //*[@id="calc08-sum"]`
I expect, that my selector is working, but unfortunately each time I get FAIL. All input fields actually fails :(

please help, how to input values into input fields and test any inputed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That element is inside an embedded iframe. You need to select the frame with [Select Frame](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) before you can interact with the elements in that frame.

For example:

```
select frame  id=calculator-frame-08a
Input Text    id=calc08-sum    1000
```